# Loops using Javascript and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, loops

Loops only show the last JSON data and I can not resolve it,  hope someone can help me and tell me what's wrong am I, thank you.

```
    <script>
  angular.module('ngMap').run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.mouseover = function() {
      console.log('mouseover', this);
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    };
    $rootScope.mouseout = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    };
    $rootScope.click = function() {console.log('click')};
    for (var i = 0; i < map_data.length; i++) {
    $rootScope.customMarkers = [
      {address: map_data[i].work_address, "class": "my1"},



    ];};
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're always assigning the `$rootScope.customMarkers =` to the `current item` in the loop. in the `last iteration` you would get the last item data. So, first create a array  `$rootScope.customMarkers = []` and then in the loop push the new object into it.

```
$rootScope.customMarkers.push({
   address: map_data[i].work_address,
   "class": "my1"
});
```

This should solve the problem.

```js
  angular.module('ngMap').run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.mouseover = function() {
      console.log('mouseover', this);
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    };
    $rootScope.mouseout = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    };
    $rootScope.customMarkers = [];
    $rootScope.click = function() {
      console.log('click')
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < map_data.length; i++) {
      $rootScope.customMarkers.push({
        address: map_data[i].work_address,
        "class": "my1"
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `angular.forEach` loop:-

```
var log = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  // Write your logic here

   this.push(key + ': ' + value);
}, log);
```

You should go through this [**link**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you create your array in each iteration, like this:

```
 $rootScope.customMarkers = [
      {address: map_data[i].work_address, "class": "my1"},



    ];};
```

Instead, you need to create the array before the loop and `push` the object in each iteration, like this:

```
$rootScope.customMarkers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < map_data.length; i++) {
    $rootScope.customMarkers.push({address: map_data[i].work_address, "class": "my1"});
};
```